# How to make a new servlet using wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

How do we make new servlet using the wizard ?

[image]

I am using eclipse kepler ide for java ee developers. Error asks to enter the project name but it doesn't allow to do so. What do I do ?

*Note: I am new to eclipse and have been using netbeans.*

Comment: You should first create a suitable project (Web/Java EE).

Comment: @HakanSerce I don't understand. I already have made a project

Comment: As @HakanSerce said, you need appropriate project to be created first.I think it should be "Dynamic web project".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to create a dynamic web project :

[image]

then you can add Servlet to the project.
if you already have a project that isn't a "Dynamic Web Project" (for example GWT) got to `Project Properties > Project Facests` and check the `Dynamic Web Module`.

[image]

Comment: I have already made one, but a _google web application project_

Comment: Though I am able to create servlet using wizard now, doesn't it automatically update the `web.xml` ?

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi This solution still doesn't work for me even after creating a dynamic web project any other alternatives?