# Cannot select the project in the Create Servlet dialog in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm experiencing an issue similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421155/how-to-make-a-new-servlet-using-wizard) but the solution provided doesn't cut it for me. So the issue in question is I can't select the project in the **Create Servlet** dialog in **Eclipse**.
This prevents me from completing the process of creating a new servlet.

As recommended by the solution I have created a **Dynamic Web Project** and have ensured that the **Dynamic Web Module** is checked in **foo -> Properties -> Project Facests**. I'm also in the **Java EE Perspective**.

Project structure:-

[image: Folder Structure]

Create servlet wizard:-
[image: New Servlet Wizard]

Project properties:-
[image: Project properties]

I'm running the following instance of **Eclipse** on **Mac OS Mojave Version 10.14.5**:-

> Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
>
> Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
> Build id: 20181214-0600

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers!

Edit (.project file) below:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <projectDescription>
      <name>Foo</name>
      <comment></comment>
      <projects>
      </projects>
      <buildSpec>
         <buildCommand>
             <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
             <arguments>
             </arguments>
         </buildCommand>
         <buildCommand>
         
     <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
     
 
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
     
 <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
     <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Does the project selector show any selectable projects?

Comment: Can you attach the .project file?

Comment: @LittleSanti no it's even interactive. Nothing happens if I click the drop-down.

Comment: @nitind I have updated the question with the .project file.

Comment: @mtotowamkwe change from dynamic web module 3.0 to 2.0

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni Just some extra information I'm using Glassfish 5.0 as the application web server. I've tried to set up the project on a Windows 10 machine and everything seems to work fine. Not sure why the issue arises on MacOS X!

Comment: Have you tried creating a package and then creating a servlet inside that?

Comment: Is there any chance that your workspace was created with a newer version of Eclipse?

Comment: @LeftistTachyon I've tried the package first then servlet approach but it didn't work. I've moved to IntelliJ IDEA as this seems like a rabbit -hole thingy!

Comment: @SteveC yes I'm using the latest version of Eclipse for Java EE developers.

Comment: "Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) Build id: 20181214-0600" is **not** the latest version. But maybe you have two versions on your machine? If you created a workspace with the new version and then attempted to manipulate your project with an old version then you might get the problem that you are experiencing. For what it is worth, I installed "Version: 2018-12" on my Mac (running Mojave) and I did not have the issue that you describe.

Comment: @SteveC nice catch. I forgot to update the screenshots in the question, my bad!. I deleted all my versions and did a clean install in order to fix the issue but it persisted thus I've jumped ship to IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better I abandoned Eclipse for IntelliJ IDEA six or seven years ago and have not looked back (except for yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

> This prevents me from completing the process of creating a new servlet.

Before a software is re-usable, it first has to be usable. *I understand your frustrations with Eclipse.* Try below steps:

1. Restart Eclipse with `-clean` argument.
2. If it still does not work, backup & delete the .metadata directory for the Eclipse workspace. .metadata is generally a hidden directory in the workspace directory. Repeat #1.
3. Disable/Remove all third party plugins which are not part of the Eclipse default package and repeat #1.

**By the way.** There is always the old school way to create a `Servlet`. You can simply create a new `Class` and make it extend `HttpServlet`, and map it in `web.xml`.

**Sample `Servlet` Java class**

```
// Import other required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

   private String message;

   public void init() throws ServletException {
      // Do required initialization
      message = "Hello World";
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
   }

   public void destroy() {
      // do nothing.
   }
}
```

**`web.xml` mapping**

```
...
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>comingsoon</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>mysite.server.ComingSoonServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>comingsoon</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```